# Garbage value even after initializing members of dynamically allocated struct array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pthreads

I have a dynamically allocated array of structures, 'buff'. Each element is a structure that has a few integer variables and a pointer 'buffer_ptr' which points to another dynamically allocated array of structures. The size of both arrays is given as command line input.

```
int buffer_size;
int user_num;
struct tuple
{
  char userID[5];
  char topic[16];
  int weight;
};
struct buff_ctrl    
{
  struct tuple* buffer_ptr;
  int in;
  int out;
  int numItems;
  int done;
};
```

The arrays are created and initialized in main() as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  void *status;
  pthread_t mapThd;
  if(argc != 4)
  {
    printf("Input format: ./combiner <buffer_size> <number_of_users> <input_file>\n");
    return -1;
  }
  buffer_size = atoi(argv[1]);
  user_num = atoi(argv[2]);
  struct buff_ctrl *buff = (struct buff_ctrl*)malloc(user_num * sizeof(struct buff_ctrl)); 
  for(int i=0; i<user_num; i++)
  {
    struct buff_ctrl* curr_buff = (buff + (i*sizeof(struct buff_ctrl)));
    struct tuple *ptr = (struct tuple*)malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(struct tuple));
    curr_buff->buffer_ptr = ptr;//points to another array
    curr_buff->in = 8;
    curr_buff->out = 4;
    curr_buff->numItems = 7;
    curr_buff->done = 0;
    printf("%p\n",curr_buff);
  }
```

Then, I need to pass the 'buff' pointer as an argument when creating thread using pthread_create:

```
  pthread_create(&mapThd, NULL, mapper, (void*)buff);
  pthread_join(mapThd, &status);
  free(buff);
  /*end of main*/
```

My function pointer is as follows:

```
void* mapper(void *buff)
{
  struct buff_ctrl* arr = (struct buff_ctrl *)buff;
  struct buff_ctrl* temp_ptr;
  printf("######################################################\n");
  for(int k=0; k<user_num; k++)
  {
    /*Printing just to check values */
    temp_ptr = arr + (k*sizeof(struct buff_ctrl));
    printf("buffer ptr =  %p\n", temp_ptr->buffer_ptr);
    printf("in =  %d\n", temp_ptr->in);
    printf("out =  %d\n", temp_ptr->out);
    printf("numItems =  %d\n", temp_ptr->numItems);
  }
  printf("######################################################\n");
  pthread_exit((void*)buff);
}
```

But, when I print the values of 'buffer_ptr' from the created thread (only one), for **ODD** number of user_num, there is always ONE element of the array 'buff' which gives garbage value **after** pthread_create statement! When the values are checked in main itself after removing calls to pthread, it runs fine.

Comment: Good first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
struct buff_ctrl* curr_buff = (buff + (i*sizeof(struct buff_ctrl)));
```

should be

```
struct buff_ctrl* curr_buff = buff + i;
```

`buff + i` is pointer arithmetic and the compiler already takes the size of the
object pointed to by `buff` into consideration. By doing `i*sizeof(struct buff_ctrl)` you are assigning
a pointer that may be after the allocated memory.

As general suggestion:

Don't cast `malloc`. And instead of using `sizeof(<type>)`, use `sizeof *variable`, this is more safe, because
it's easier to make mistakes when writing `sizeof(<type>)`.

So:

```
struct buff_ctrl *buff = malloc(user_num * sizeof *buff);

...

struct tuple *ptr = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof *ptr);
```

And you don't need to declare a separate pointer, you can do:

```
for(int i=0; i<user_num; i++)
{
    buff[i].buffer_ptr = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof *buff[i].buffer_ptr);
    buff[i].in = 8;
    buff[i].out = 4;
    buff[i].numItems = 7;
    buff[i].done = 0;
}
```

Also you should always check for the return value of `malloc`. If it returns
`NULL`, you cannot access that memory.

Comment: Wow. That was only 8 seconds earlier than mine.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi for me was the other way round, when I pressed "Add answer" I saw yours.

Comment: Yes, in fact ordering by "*oldest*" shows mine as the first answer to this question. I think that it was quite evident that this was causing problems, I immediately realized it.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi what caused problems?

Comment: This `struct buff_ctrl *buff = malloc(user_num * sizeof *buff);` and other similar ones.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi now I'm confused. I though that both answers came almost immediately were causing problems. Or did you mean that I wrote something wrong regarding `malloc`?

Comment: nothing. I mean that we both noticed the problem because it was too evident. Your answer is very nice, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
struct buff_ctrl* curr_buff = (buff + (i*sizeof(struct buff_ctrl)));
```

When you do pointer arithmetic, it operates in units of the size of what the pointer points to, so you don't need to multiply by `sizeof`. As a result, you're effectively multiplying twice and accessing outside the array bounds.

Just treat `buff` as an array, rather than dealing with pointers.

```
  for(int i=0; i<user_num; i++)
  {
    struct tuple *ptr = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(struct tuple));
    buff[i].buffer_ptr = ptr;//points to another array
    buff[i].in = 8;
    buff[i].out = 4;
    buff[i].numItems = 7;
    buff[i].done = 0;
  }
```

Also, see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental error.

Pointer arithmetics works by adding the offset in multiples of the pointer type, so adding the offset yourself will not work as you apparently expect it to.

If it was a `char *` pointer then you would need to add the offset manually, increments would be multiplied by one. But in your case increments by `n` are multiplied by the size of the pointer base type.

There are times when doing pointer arithmetics with the addition notation makes sense, but most of the time it's much clearer to write index notation instead.